# How do I build a regular expression containing a dynamic string in TypeScript?

Tags: regex, typescript

I would like to write a regular expression which matches one or more occurrences of:

- exactly two open curly braces, followed by
- zero or more spaces, followed by
- a dynamic string, followed by
- zero or more spaces, followed by
- exactly two closed curly braces

Let's say I have a fixed string `hello`. Then the regular expression which matches the above-mentioned pattern would be:

```regex
/({{\s*hello\s*}}){1,}/gi
```

In TypeScript, this would become:

```js
const regExp: RegExp = /({{\s*hello\s*}}){1,}/gi;
```

If I were to use that regular expression with the following array of strings I would get these results:

1. `{{ hello }}`: 1 match
2. `{{ hello}}`: 1 match
3. `{{hello }}`: 1 match
4. `{{hello}}`: 1 match
5. `{hello}}`: 0 matches
6. `{{hello}`: 0 matches
7. `{ hello }`: 0 matches
8. `{{hello}}, how are you? {{ hello }}`: 2 matches
9. `{{hello}}, how are you? {{ hello }} {{hello}}`: 3 matches
10. `{{HELLO}}`: 1 match

However, I am not able to achieve the same result by using a dynamic string.

Comment: I really do not understand how the linked answer would answer my question. In [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494046/3628251) they are using a static value, whereas my problem consisted in concatenating a piece of regular expression, the variable, and the other piece of regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find the solution by myself while writing the question. There are several different available approaches. The following regular expression initialisations are equivalent:

```js
const key = 'hello';

// Static regular expressions
const regExp: RegExp = /({{\s*hello\s*}}){1,}/gi;
const staticSingleQuotedRegExp = new RegExp('({{\\s*hello\\s*}}){1,}', "gi");
const staticDoubleQuotedRegExp = new RegExp("(\{\{\\s*hello\\s*\}\}){1,}", "gi");

// Dynamic regular expressions
const dynamicSingleQuotedRegExp = new RegExp('({{\\s*' + key + '\\s*}}){1,}', "gi");
const backtickedRegExp = new RegExp(`({{\\s*${key}\\s*}}){1,}`, "gi");
const dynamicDoubleQuotedRegExp = new RegExp("(\{\{\\s*" + key + "\\s*\}\}){1,}", "gi");
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-a4j367?file=index.ts) is a stackblitz example.

Comment: You forget that your approach will fail if `key` contains special regex metacharacters. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).